# Water always coming out of my perimeter drain around my house

Tags: drain, french-drain

I have a brand new energy efficient home that was built in 2019 as a part of a new development and of course it has a perimeter drain system with a pipe coming out to the edge of the street.

I just noticed that water never stops coming out of my perimeter drain. All the new houses around me does not have that issue. My house is the only one with water constantly coming out and the builder said there's no issue and in fact it's a good thing that water is always coming out as it's a sign the system is working great.

I'm not convinced since no other houses have the water coming out like mine. 
Also when the propane company comes to fill my underground propane tank, they told me the water around the opening is higher than usual.

What could be the issue and how to fix it? My house still within the 1 year warranty so i want to fix any potential problem.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Is there a pump driving this drain? Could you add a picture or two? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: i don't have any pumps. it's a perimeter drain that's gravity driven i believe

Comment: Moe, please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how this network operates.

Answer (score 1):

There is water in the ground, and the drain is moving the water to the gutter at the curbside. Your builder is correct, the drain is working.

The real question is: where is the groundwater coming from? Have you had a lot of rain lately? Are your neighbors running their sprinklers in the winter? It's also possible that your (or your neighbor's) potable water main is leaking. You also could be the lucky owner of a home that is built on or near a natural spring.

Did your builder do any sort of percolation test or evaluation of the ground water situation?

Comment: The drain is working that's for sure but none of my neighbors running any sprinkler in the winter. I also checked for a water leak in my house and nothing to show any leak by looking at the meter and testing it. I'm just wondering why am i the only house with water constantly coming out of the perimeter drain?

Comment: Water flow can be a very localized thing. The soil type may be different, there might be a layer of clay between you and your neighbors that the water doesn't penetrate, there might be a "trough" of gravel that directs the water towards your home, etc. Your neighbors might have a water problem they don't know about yet.

Answer (score 0):

Localized underground drainage is common. Water doesn't follow many rules, and who knows what's going on down there between you and your neighbors? You might just be the luck one over a vein. There are several homes on my block with almost year-round pumping going on, while mine basically dries up in winter.

The good news is that you have a gravity-driven system and aren't paying for a sump pump to run frequently.

Comment: Thanks... I just want to understand and find the reason why i have a running water out of my perimeter ALL the time? it's driving me crazy

Answer (score 0):

First a modern house with a sealed chamber furnace & AC or a heat pump will have a constant water flow and may be being dumped into the premier drain.  if you think you have a leak make sure every water tap is turned off and go check the water meter. No movement your water source is the heating and cooling system or ground water.

With a high water level around your propane tank would bother me but there could be a spring there that adds to any possible water runoff.

I would check the water meter first, then be looking at tying a French drain into the perimeter drain if you have enough elevation to drain the propane tank well I have found many springs over the years that were not detected when we set the foundation and ended up with moisture problems that in some cases French drains solved the issue in others sealing the slab was needed.

Comment: i do have a heat pump and central air but i'm not sure why would those dump water into the drainage system? I also checked my water meter for any water leak when all my taps are off and there's nothing and i also checked my sprinkler system and no leak there. How can i find if there's any spring around? it's a new development and all houses next to each other and i think if there's a spring somewhere, it would cause similar issues to my neighbors but none of them seem to have that issue.

Comment: The last track of homes we built had 1 lot with 2 springs none of the others had any water, as far as water when the heat pump is in heat mode water is generated at the outside unit, depending on if full split or mini split there may be multiple points that drain outside the home from the inside units when cooling , it’s just how they work., since you are the only one it is probably a spring.

Comment: Thanks Ed. If this is the case, is there anything i should do or should be worried about? I'm trying to see my options to avoid any future issues